# Wrap text in Paint (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml, paint

I'm using the Paint function and i set the text with the setText method. The problem is that if the text is very large (many words) the text go out of the parent. How can i fix this? Maybe wrap when the text is bigger than the parent. i use this code (for the moment)

```
    mSubtitlePaint.setTextSize(17); 
    mSubtitlePaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    mSubtitlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mSubtitlePaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create("Roboto-Thin", Typeface.BOLD));
```

For the moment i resolve setting the textSize at 17 instead of 20 but i search a better solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to mention `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` in text view tag

Comment: What? I haven't none textview!

Comment: That is what you have declared it in xml file..

Comment: are you trying to write to a canvas?

Comment: @shylendra Where are you seeing a `TextView` in this question?